# How to perform ANOVA in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, statistics, anova

So I have these 2 variables:

```
x: 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
```

and

```
y: 4 3 12 9 2 7 23 ...
```

Previously I can perform ANOVA in `R` with this code:

```
stats <- anova( lm( as.matrix(y) ~ as.factor(x) ) )
```

and it will give this result:

```
> anova( lm( as.matrix(y) ~ as.factor(x) ) )
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: as.matrix(y)
               Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
as.factor(x)   1   2020 2019.99  5.1431 0.02426 *
Residuals     231  90727  392.76                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Now I want to translate this code to Spark using Scala code. How to do this?

I already tried [this API](https://gist.github.com/srnghn/c74835818802fefabd76f1bcd6746831#file-anova_spark_2-0-scala-L35), but I'm confused since in that API only take 1 variable as input, but the `anova` in `R` use 2 inputs.

I also found [this API](https://github.com/hhbyyh/StatisticsOnSpark/blob/master/src/main/ANOVA/OneWayANOVA.scala), but it seems like it's the predecessor of the other one. I'm confused about where to put the `x` and `y` as the inputs. Usually we have dependent & independent variables inside the API where we can put the inputs, but I can't seem to find it in here.

My Spark version is 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R` you need to provide a mapping from y ~ x, where `y` is a continuous and `x` is a categorical variable. It's the same in the `Spark` code you quoted:

```
val catTuple = spark.sql("select color, price from cars").toDF(colnames: _*).as[CatTuple]
```

Here `color` is the categorical and `price` is the continuous variable.

In your second example (weird data structure!), you need to provide an `Iterable[RDD[Double]]`, which means that each category in your data should be put in a separate RDD.

Comment: Thanks man! Really explaining! I'm curious, do you know why in `R` we need to do linear regression first? (as in the code `lm( as.matrix(y) ~ as.factor(x) )` )

Comment: If you do that you are looking at the ANOVA table for the fitted regression model.  Some more details here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/anova.lm.html and here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115304/interpreting-output-from-anova-when-using-lm-as-input